# Como poner en un nuevo array un vector sin espacios vacios

Tags: java, netbeans-8.2

Primer array

```
String datos[]={"hola", "", "como", "", "", "estas", ""};
```

Hacer un algoritmo que te salte los espacios vacios
y que te de en un nuevo array

```
datos new[]={"hola", "como", "estas"};
```

en java porfavor

**Esto es lo que tengo hasta ahora**

```
String[] datosnew = new String[datos.length]; 
for (int i = 0; i < datos.length; i++) { 
  if (datos[i].equals("")) { 

  } 
}
```

Comment: Lo que pides es muy sencillo, has intentado algo hasta ahora?

Comment: Si pero solo llegue hasta aca soy nuevo en esto u.u String[] datosnew = new String[datos.length];

 for (int i = 0; i < datos.length; i++) {
                    if (datos[i].equals("")) {
                        

                    }
}

Comment: Bien ya tienes casi todo el código listo, solo necesitas unos ajustes.

Comment: ayudame porfavor u.u

Comment: Deberías editar la pregunta y añadir ahí el código, no en un comentario. Una pregunta que no demuestra un esfuerzo previo para resolver un problema suele ser candidata a ser cerrada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como lo que quieres es que `datosnew` almacene los datos de las posiciones que no están en blanco ("") del array `datos`, el tamaño del array `datosnew` debe ser de 3, ya que ese es el numero de posiciones con datos en el array `datos`. Si creas el array `datosnew` con el mismo tamaño que el array `datos`, al final tendrás el mismo numero de posiciones, pero en vez de estar vacias ("") estas tendrían el valor de `null`, ya que si creas un array de tipo String y no rellenas sus posiciones, el valor por defecto de estas sera null.

Después, como estas haciendo, recorres el array `datos` con un ciclo y con un condicional evalúas si las posiciones no están vacías (""). Si la posición no esta vacía, almacenas los datos de esa posición en el array `datosnew`; fuera del condicional creas un contador que incremente su valor cada vez que se cumpla la condición del if, para ir almacenando los datos del array `datos` en diferentes posiciones del array `datosnew`.

```
String datos[] = {"hola", "", "como", "", "", "estas", ""};
String[] datosnew = new String[3];
int j = 0; 
for (int i = 0; i < datos.length; i++) {

    if (!datos[i].equals("")) {
        datosnew[j] = datos[i];
        j++;
    } 
}
```

> `!` es un operador booleano que invierte una operación booleana, si una operación booleana es verdadera la convierte en falsa y viceversa.

Comment: Muchas Gracias, enserio lo necesitaba

Comment: He actualizado la respuesta, léela para que entiendas mejor como funciona y pon aprueba todo lo que dice. Tal como dice @PabloLozano agrega el código de tu comentario a la pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

En Java 8 lo puedes realizar con streams, simplemente filtrando los que estén vacíos:

```
import java.util.Arrays; 
import java.util.List; 
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

class Main {   
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    String datos[] = {"hola", "", "como", "", "", "estas", ""};
    List<String> datosFiltrados = Arrays.asList(datos).stream().filter(d -> !d.isEmpty()).collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(datosFiltrados);   
 } 
}
```

Te dará, como resultado:

```
[hola, como, estas]
```

Código funcionando: [link](https://repl.it/repls/ThreadbareMatureAnnelida)

En Java 8 el uso de streams nos permite manipular y procesar más fácilmente las fuentes de datos, en este caso, una lista de strings. En el ejemplo, usamos el `stream()` para recorrer la lista; con el método `filter()`, filtramos la lista especificándole una expresión que valide si el dato `d` no está vacío (en caso de que esté vacío, lo ignora) y el método `collect()` para retornar la lista resultada.

Esta solución es más limpia y es perfecta para empezar a aprender a usar listas con streams. Saludos.